# How to make a MGLPolyline tapable?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I am currently looking for a way to make a route (MGPLPolyline) tappable such that a user can choose between two possible routes under Mapbox. Unfortunately the route annotation  doesn't seem to be tappable at all:

While i have properly set my `MGLMapViewDelegate` this method:

`func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didSelect annotation: MGLAnnotation)`

is never invoked.

What did i miss knowing that each line inherited from `MGLPolyline` which is a subclass of an `MGLAnnotation` (which i was expected to be tappable...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mapbox iOS API doesn't support that yet, unfortunately. [See here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/2082).

There are a couple of workarounds within that link that you could try though.

UPDATE:
This is now possible: [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54586620/is-it-possible-to-make-mglpolylines-selectable-swift-mapbox).

Comment: Is this still true? in 2019?

Comment: @user123 This appears to have been implemented now. I haven't played around with it too much but have added a fuller answer to your newer question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

First, when you create the polyline do the following:

```
let polyline = CustomPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: UInt(coordinates.count))

polyline.title = "" //It does not seem to matter what you set it to.

polyline.color = .darkGray
```

Then in the following method return false:

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
    // Always allow callouts to popup when annotations are tapped.
    print("ran?")
    return false
}
```